# How to debug IACCVIOL where all registers have been cleared?

Tags: debugging, rust, embedded, stm32, stm32f7

I'm developing a complex and intricate app for STM32F746. I stumbled upon the following hard fault and I'm not sure how to find the origin of the problem :

```
16:05:51.832 HardFault : ExceptionFrame { r0: 0xffffffff, r1: 0xffffffff, r2: 0xffffffff, r3: 0xffffffff, r12: 0xffffffff, lr: 0xffffffff, pc: 0xffffffff, xpsr: 0xffffffff }
16:05:51.832 UFSR : 0000000000000000
16:05:51.832 BFSR : 00000000
16:05:51.832 MMFSR : 00000001
16:05:51.832 HFSR : 01000000000000000000000000000000
```

The MMFSR part of the CFSR clearly indicates the error is IACCVIOL. Unfortunately, MMARVALID is not set, so I can't use the MMFAR to find the root of the issue.

Stepping through with GDB takes a huge amount of time for very little progress, as I need to start over every time the fault appears. I couldn't find a way to record/replay the session to quickly track down the issue in GDB.

**Is there an approach that could help me pinpoint where the code fails ?**

Comment: I bet that the stack pointer points to the wrong place. I would not debug manually only use IDE with some useful plugins giving you for example names of the bits. It is 21st century.

Comment: What debug hardware do you have? Does your board expose the trace pins?  That is the simplest way of resolving such problems, but is not always available, and the debug hardware is expensive.

Comment: The debug hardware available is the st-link chip integrated in the STM32F7 DISCO board. The IDE I'm using is VSCode with rust-analyzer, it doesn't support embedded debugging so this is done through gdb with OpenOCD or cargo-embed